# accent characters crash IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, unicode, crash

I'm working on a multilingual site using Umbraco CMS.  When testing IE9, I found several pages that force IE9 to close (and only certain versions or builds of IE9). I've narrowed it down to accented characters.  However, the pages that work have accented characters as well. To figure out what the difference is, I copied the offending text into Notepad from both working and non-working pages. I am unable to add a screenshot from notepad b/c I'm new so I'll have to describe it:

The first word with 'í' crashes IE9. The 'í' character does not look correct; there is no kerning, it's smaller, just looks like it is not rendering as part of the font.  The second word with 'í' does not crash IE9. It renders correctly as part of the font. I get the same, correct character by typing (alt/option+e)+i.

I apologize if there is a term for this difference but I'm having a difficult time searching for such a specific problem without knowing what to search for. The editor who is adding the data to the site copies content from multiple sources so I'm assuming that is the source of the problem, but I would like to control this and keep it from happening again. Can I validate this kind of problem on input? What is the technical difference between these two characters?

**MORE INFORMATION**

IE9 Version: 9.0.8112.16421
Update Versions: 9.0.15 (KB2817183)

I did more digging and I've found that when pasting the bad character 'í' in this ASCII converter: http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/ it returns an ASCII value of 105 (which is the same as the letter 'i'.  When I paste the correct character 'í' in the converter, I get an ASCII value of 237.

I've also found the source of the problem. The bad character comes from a pdf.  When an editor copies from a particular pdf and pastes it into the CMS I get the bad character. So far, any character with an accent mark is breaking my version of IE9.

Below is a snippet of code used to display the content on the front-end of the site. I'm using Umbraco CMS version 6.1, Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, my views are .cshtml:

```
@{

   XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
   xd.LoadXml(Model);

}

@foreach(XmlNode widget in xd.SelectNodes("//widget")){
   <h4>@widget.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText</h4>
}
```

To reiterate, is there a way to 'protect' or validate against these types of character problems? I'm assuming no, since the ASCII converter recognizes the bad character as an 'i', but I'm concerned that the editor adding information could add a bad character and no one would know unless they happened to look at the site in IE9...

Thanks!

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the issue and specify the build of IE 9. Even then, this might remain off-topic, since debugging (closed-code) browsers is hardly suitable for SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added more information to my original post. I'm not interested in debugging IE, but I am wondering if there is a way to check for characters that are either not known or are incorrectly rendered, be it a server side or client side solution. But at this point I'm not optimistic that I'm able to differentiate between these 'bad' and 'good' characters...